# Complex algebraic group is reductive $\iff$ it is the complexification of a compact Lie group?

Tags: algebraic-geometry, lie-groups, algebraic-groups

By a complex reductive algebraic group I mean the group of complex points of a (possibly disconnected) affine algebraic group defined over $\mathbb{C}$ whose unipotent radical (maximal connected unipotent normal subgroup) is trivial.

I can't seem to find a clear source for the following fact that I believe to be true:

A complex algebraic group is reductive if and only if it is the complexification of a compact Lie group.

Comment: So when you say the complexification of a Lie group, you mean purely as a group? Since clearly the topologies will not look remotely the same.

Comment: @Victor: Which direction do you find unclear?

Comment: @studiosus I am most concerned with $\implies$.

Comment: @TobiasKildetoft I believe you can realize a compact Lie group as a real algebraic group in $GL_n\mathbb{R}$ and then complexification can be interpreted as taking the complex zeroes of its defining polynomials in $GL_n\mathbb{C}$.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

This result is true and not easy. You can find this result stated and a proof of "complexification of compact group implies reductive" in [chapter 5 of these notes](http://www.math.toronto.edu/jkamnitz/courses/reptheory/reptheory.pdf).

I don't know a proof of the converse that doesn't already establish a substantial part of the classification of reductive groups. In the case that $G$ is centerless and simple, you can see a proof as [Lemma 2 here](http://terrytao.wordpress.com/2013/09/05/notes-on-simple-groups-of-lie-type/).

One sign that it is hard is that you need to use the hypothesis that your complex group is a linear algebraic group. For example, let $E$ be an elliptic curve over $\mathbb{C}$. Then $E$ is a group object in the category of $\mathbb{C}$ varieties which is not the complexification of any compact group. Indeed, if the $j$-invariant of $E$ is not real, then $E$ doesn't even have any anti-holomorphic involutions.

Comment: (Part 1) Thank you for your answer. One of the lines in the UofT notes is a really good summary of the type of statement found throughout the literature on this question: "I think this is an equivalence of categories".

After a lot more searching, I think I may have found what I want in the book "Lie Groups and Algebraic Groups" by Onishchik & Vinberg but there's a problem. In Chapter 5, Section 2, they establish a 1-1 correspondence between compact Lie groups (up to differentiable isomorphism) and reductive complex algebraic groups (up to polynomial isomorphism) given by complexification.

Comment: (part 2) I would be happy with this, $except$ they seem to define complex reductive groups in terms of their Lie algebra.
They define a complex Lie algebra $\mathfrak{g}$ to be reductive if it splits as $\mathfrak{g}=\mathfrak{z}(\mathfrak{g})\oplus[\mathfrak{g},\mathfrak{g}]$ and define a complex algebraic group $G$ to be reductive if its tangent algebra is reductive. But in this case, isn't the additive group $\mathbb{C}$ a counterexample? I feel like I'm missing a basic point here.

Comment: I agree that the definition of reductive you quote above would imply that $\mathbb{C}$ is reductive; that no algebraic geometer considers $\mathbb{C}$ to be reductive; and that $\mathbb{C}$ is not the complexification of a compact Lie group. I'm not sure what to say beyond that. Perhaps try binary search: Read a statement in the middle of their proof and decide whether you think it is true or false when $G=\mathbb{C}$, then search forward or backward accordingly.

Comment: @DavidSpeyer: should "not hard" in the third paragraph read "hard"? (Not that this is vitally important to your answer.)

Comment: @AsalBeagDubh Fixed, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

For the $\Rightarrow$ direction you just use Weyl unitary trick in the semisimple part and the fact that $C^*$ is the complexification of $R^*$ for the abelian part.

Comment: I'm not quite sure what you mean. Could you please expand your answer?